# How to know which partition column is

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using Cosmos - DocumentDB. 
I don't have the rights to access Azure Portal.

But I need to know which column is partition column. 
I only can access via AuthorizationKey.

Is there any way to reach that?

Comment: Can't you ask the person who created the collection? Presumably someone at your work set things up for you and there's a reason you don't have full access to the portal

Comment: @JesseCarter I can ask him about this matter but I don't want to do that. I would like to find out another way!

Answer (score 0):

You can call the ReadDocumentCollectionAsync API and check the value of PartitionKey.Paths[0] as below:

```
DocumentCollection collection = client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(collectionUri).Result;

Console.WriteLine(collection.PartitionKey.Paths[0]);
```

- Rajesh,
  Azure Cosmos DB